# Как правильно делать анимацию с помощью js и css?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

Есть вот такая простая анимация с помощью `transition`:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

btn.addEventListener('click', animateSquare);

function animateSquare() {
  div.classList.toggle('move-forward');
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.move-forward {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class='move-backward'></div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Правильно ли сделать то же самое с помощью `keyframes` вот так?

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

btn.addEventListener('click', animateSquare);

function animateSquare() {
  if (div.classList.contains('move-forward')) {
    div.classList.remove('move-forward');
    div.classList.add('move-backward');

  } else {
    div.classList.remove('move-backward');
    div.classList.add('move-forward');

  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.move-forward {
  animation: move-forward 1s forwards;
}

.move-backward {
  animation: move-backward 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes move-forward {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}

@keyframes move-backward {
  from {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Есть ощущение, что я что то делаю не так и это можно сделать как то короче... или сделать вообще по другому...объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно такие вещи делаются.

Comment: В обоих примерах все хорошо, и все верно... Не понятно, что смущает...

Comment: Единственное, в таком простом примере, вполне можно обойтись просто трансформацией, анимации нужны для более сложных решений...